# Preventing traffic from circumventing a landing page

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess, http-redirect

I have a website where, when visitors land on any of a several landing pages (different languages), they are given an opportunity to enter any of a number of promotion codes into a form. If they enter one of the correct codes (stored on a SQL table), they go to another page with a form where they can give their mailing info to receive a free product. If the code they entered isn't on the table, they get a message the code they entered is invalid and are blocked.

This works through php. When the landing page form is entered and submitted, a URL something like this: website.com/formentry.php?promo=code is generated where 'code' matches whatever the user entered into the form. If “code" matches a string in the code column in the database table, they get sent to the entry form. If it doesn’t, they get blocked. To this point, everything works great and has been running smoothly for months.

However a problem has been identified recently: The landing pages can be circumvented by entering website.com/formentry.php?code=code directly into a browser’s URL field. This is a problem for several reasons and I need to prevent it from being possible.

Does anyone have any ideas for a solution; perhaps using the .htaccess file to send those URL requests back to the landing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sessions, you can set the user's session when they enter the correct code on the landing page:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION[valid_user] = true;
```

Then, on every other page (non-landing-page), you put a validator like:

```
if (!$_SESSION[valid_user])
{
  echo "You do not have permission to view this page";
}
```

Or, instead of showing an error message, you can redirect the user to another page:

```
if (!$_SESSION[valid_user])
{
  $url = "http://example.com";
  header("Location: $url");
  exit();
}
```

If you want to take this one step further, let's say the auth. code is 420. You can set the landing page to take the submitted code and set

`$_SESSION[420] = true;`

and on the page for product #420, or whatever, validate, as above, that the user's session contains `420 == true`. That way, if they use coupon code 420, they're only authorized to see product #420's page, not all product pages.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed help, @jacey! However, I've followed your instructions to the best of my abilities and something is not working. I've added 

$_SESSION[valid_user] = true; 

to the landing page, and 

if (!$_SESSION[valid_user]) {  echo "You do not have permission to view this page"; }

to the entry form page, and the echoed message appears even when I go through the landing page properly to get to the entry page. Could there be something in the code that negates the true value of the $_SESSION?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your current program on the landing page checks to see if the code is valid. Use that same code to set the session. I don't know what your landing page code does now, but it might be something like, "If the code is valid, take the user to the correct page". Change your code slightly to be something like, "If the code is valid, set the SESSION variable, then take the user to the correct page". If the code isn't valid, do not set the session variable.

Comment: Hi Jacey, it looks like it wasn't working because I didn't include session_start();  before declaring the session. Once I added that line of code at the top of both pages, your solution works! Thanks for you help.

Comment: @MatthewLoboWillis: Excellent! I'll make that more clear in my answer. Please remember to upvote!

Comment: consider yourself upvoted! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the promo codes not via URL, but through [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will look into php sessions and try to figure out how to implement a solution that way. Currently my PHP skills are not strong enough to include them.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it and at the same time protect your self from Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF).

Here is how:

- Generate a hash, guid or something like that (use random_bytes is a good option).
- Save this hash in the session.
- Then add the hash in a hidden field of the form.
- Use POST method instead of GET in the form.
- And in the page that receives the request compare the given hash with the one in the session and if doesn't match or is not present then throw an error.

In many ways this give your a better protection.

Some sample code you could use.

```
<?php
// In the page you have the form:

// Generate the string
$csrf_value = str_replace(['/', '+', '='], '', base64_encode(random_bytes(20)));
// Save it in the session
$_SESSION['csrf'] = $csrf_value;
?>

<form action"a_page.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?php echo $csrf_value ?>" />
    <input type="textfield" name="code" />
</form>
```

In the page that receives the request:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['csrf']) 
        && strlen($_POST['csrf']) > 0 
        && strcmp($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf']) === 0) {
    // All good, do your thing
} else {
    // Show error, this guy is trying to trick you
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will try that. I haven't known about random_bytes, so that's good to know!